# Time driven trigger, but having trouble referencing the sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp, crontrigger

Trying to create a trigger to add a timestamp to a column, if that row was edited at some point that day. Its for work, they feel that onEdit is too messy. I don't know either.

So, I have a trigger set up to run at 1pm every day. That part works. However, I don't know how to make the code for the timestamp to point to that triggered event, and I don't know how to write out that particular function. This is what I've got, it hits line ten and says the source is defined as null. Am I looking for the triggerUiD that it needs, or something else?

```
function myFunction(event) {
  var timeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
  var timestamp_format = "MM-dd-yyy hh:mm:ss";
  var updateColName = "Updated";
  var timeStampColName = "Timestamp";
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("TestTimestamp");
  var actRng = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveRange();
  var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
  var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
  var headers = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("TestTimestamp").getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf(timeStampColName);
  var updateCol = headers[0].indexOf(updateColName); updateCol = updateCol+1;
  if (dateCol > -1 && index > 1 && editColumn == updateCol) {
      var cell = sheet.getRange(index, dateCol +1);
      var date = Utilities.formateDate(new Date(), timezone, timestamp_format);
      cell.setValue(date);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Line 10 sheet is undefined in `var headers = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("TestTimestamp").getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();`

You could rewrite it like this:

```
function myFunction(event) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var timeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
  var timestamp_format = "MM-dd-yyy hh:mm:ss";
  var updateColName = "Updated";
  var timeStampColName = "Timestamp";
  var source = ss.getSheetByName("TestTimestamp");
  var actRng = ss.getActiveRange();
  var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
  var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
  var sheet=ss.getSheetByName('TestTimestamp'');
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  var dateCol = headers.indexOf(timeStampColName);
  var updateCol = headers.indexOf(updateColName); updateCol = updateCol+1;
  if (dateCol > -1 && index > 1 && editColumn == updateCol) {
    var cell = sheet.getRange(index, dateCol +1);
    var date = Utilities.formateDate(new Date(), timezone, timestamp_format);
    cell.setValue(date);
  }
}
```